# Is it possible to decode a text with more than encrypted values in Java?

Tags: java, spring, encryption, hash

Into same folder, I want to save files with having same name. It is not possible, of course. Not to lead confusions in the future, In Java I want to hash or encrypt file name with different values then save it. When I callback (I will call with some Id), I want to decrypt and get their names.

I came up with this with this idea, but I am open to different solution.
Thanks

Comment: You can't save 2 files with the same name in the same folder.

Comment: I know. English is not my main language. Probably I misunderstood. I want to process name of file, in java then save with that generated name. But when I call it with some, also, geneareted id I want to decode its name.

Comment: @yardımcıEtis Are you trying to write a Cryptolocker? (Remember, you must answer truthfully on the Internet.) Anyway, encryption is a simple pseudo-random permutation. So, if you decrypt a single encrypted filename with two different keys, you get to different decrypted filenames which are "valid". Also, encryption is reversible, but hashing is not reversible. Please don't confuse the two. It's probably not what you wanted to read, but that is only because I didn't understand your question. Can you ask somebody else to help you express yourself better?

Comment: How will encoding or encrypting the filename solve your problem?  Identical names will encrypt to identical values.  (And why is this tagged with “spring”?)

Comment: @Artjom B thanks for comment. No my purpose is not Cryptolocker. My purpose was naming. I think I should find another simple way to do that like giving counter or something else.

Comment: @VGR thanks for comment. I work with spring framework, so i tagged and you are right encryption doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Why not just use the names `File_1` and `File_2`? Ignore everything after the `_` and you have two identical file names.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to add a sequence number or a timestamp after the file name. And remove it while serving it to the end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have two `xxx.txt` files you want to copy to the directory. Then one could save them as `xxx.txt.1` and `xxx.txt.2`. The original file name is still there.

You might the use the same encryption/decryption for all file names if you need unreadable names.

Comment: Thank you. I wil continue accoding to your your suggestion.